# NoMethodError for *_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to create an "edit" link for a nested resource on a view template. The parent resource is Project and the child resource is Requirement. I get the following error when loading the Project show template:

> NoMethodError in Projects#show
>   undefined method `edit_requirement_path' for ##Class:0x000001009e5bc8>:0x00000100f83760>

Below is the code from the Requirements partial (`_requirement.html.erb`).

```
<%= div_for requirement do %>
  <h4>
    <%= requirement.name  %>
  </h4>
  <p><b>Type: </b><%= requirement.requirement_type.name %></p>
  <p><b>Priority: </b><%= requirement.requirement_priority.name %></p>
  <p><b>Detail: </b><%= simple_format requirement.detail %></p>
  <p><b>Initiator: </b><%= requirement.initiator %></p>
  <p><b>Approved: </b>
  <% if requirement.approved? %>
    Yes
  <% else %>
    No
  <% end %>
  </p>
  <%= link_to 'Edit Requirement', edit_requirement_path(@requirement)%>
<% end %>
```

This is the code for the Edit action in the RequirementsController.

```
class RequirementsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def edit
    @requirement = Requirement.find(params[:id])
  end
  ...
```

This is the code from the Project show template (`show.html.erb`).
    ...

**Start date:**
      <%= @project.start_date %>

```
<p>
  <b>End date:</b>
  <%= @project.end_date %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Requirements Approved:</b>
  <%= @project.requirements_approved %>%
</p>

<div id="requirements_display">
<h3>Project Requirements</h3>
  <%= render @project.requirements %>
</div>

<div id="requirements_module">
<h3>Add New Requirement</h3>
<%= render :file => "requirements/new" %>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>
```

And this is the code from the routes.rb file.

```
Nexus::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :requirement_priorities
  resources :project_services

  root :to => "projects#index"

  resources :projects do
    resources :requirements
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

On the line:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Requirement', edit_requirement_path(@requirement)%>
```

you're passing in an instance variable `@requirement` instead of the local variable `requirement` (no @ symbol).

Does it work if you remove the @?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The error does persist if I remove the instance symbol. The reference to the class, however, does change. With the @ throws: "#<#<Class:0x000001009ae150>:0x000001023cb4c0>" while without the @ throws "#<#<Class:0x000001009ae150>:0x00000100a82f18".